# Parent key not found after upgrading spring boot from 2.1.1 to 2.2.10

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am having an error ***ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ADDRESS_R01) violated - parent key not found*** after I updated the spring boot version in my application. The error is happening when the function ***userRepository.save*** is called, which should trigger the save in users table first and after that the save in address table.

When I enable show_sql, I can see that what is happening is that address is being saved before the users, and the error above is thrown. Which does not happen in previous version.

If I downgrade the spring boot to 2.1.1, which was the version before, everything works fine. I want to know what could be the problem, since I could not find any reference to this problem related to the spring boot version.

The relationship between these two tables are represented in the classes below using @OneToOne annotation.

PS: this is not the whole class, it is just an example of how the relation ship is being handled. As you can see, the column ID in users is used in @JoinColumn annotation too.

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class UserEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 40)
  public String getId()
  {
    return this.id;
  }

  @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", length = 75, nullable = false)
  @NotNull
  public String getFirstName()
  {
    return this.firstName;
  }

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
  }
```

And Address entity which looks like this:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

  @Id
  @Column(
      name = "id",
      unique = true,
      nullable = false,
      length = 40)
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "address", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  public UserEntity getUser() {
    return this.user;
  }

  public void setUser(UserEntity user) {
    this.user = user;
  }
```

PS:

1. The FK is in Adress Table. ID is a FK and a PK
2. The entities has a shared id, the id is the same in both tables

EDIT1: I found that out that the error happens on version 2.2.X. In 2.1.X version it works perfectly.

EDIT2: If I invert the @JoinColumn annotation with mappedBy it will work in version 2.2.X. I want to know why

Comment: Most likely you have not set both sides of the relationship before saving. `user.setAdress(...)` and `address.setUser(...)`

Comment: I did it, I will edit, I just posted this classes as an example. It works perfect in previous version @AlanHay